# How to add button icons to ActionBar in Nativescript?

Tags: android, xml, telerik, nativescript

**Hi there people!**

I'm trying to add a hamburger menu icon to the ActionBar in my Nativescript app that would trigger a side drawer, but I can't get to add that menu icon.

This is the [official documentation on the matter](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#creating-slidedrawer-button);

And this is my `.xml` code so far:

```
<dpg:DrawerPage loaded="pageLoaded" navigatedTo="onNavigatingTo"  
xmlns:dpg="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/drawerpage"
xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer"
xmlns:sdc="views/side-drawer-content"
xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
<navigation.actionBar>
  <ActionBar title="Drawer Over Navigation">
    <android>
      <NavigationButton icon="res://ic_menu" tap="toggleDrawer" />
    </android>
    <ios>
      <ActionItem icon="res://ic_menu" ios.position="left" tap="toggleDrawer" />
    </ios>
  </ActionBar>
</navigation.actionBar>

<dpg:DrawerPage.sideDrawer>
<drawer:RadSideDrawer id="drawer">
  <drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
    <sdc:side-drawer-content />
  </drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
</drawer:RadSideDrawer> 
</dpg:DrawerPage.sideDrawer>

<StackLayout cssClass="mainContent">
    <Label text="{{ exampleText }}" textWrap="true" cssClass="drawerContentText"/>
    <Button text="Toggle Drawer" tap="toggleDrawer" icon="res://ic_menu" />
</StackLayout>
</dpg:DrawerPage>
```

I think the relevant part is here, but I can't see what could be my mistake.

```
<ActionBar title="Drawer Over Navigation">
    <android>
      <NavigationButton icon="res://ic_menu" tap="toggleDrawer" />
    </android>
    <ios>
      <ActionItem icon="res://ic_menu" ios.position="left" tap="toggleDrawer" />
    </ios>
</ActionBar>
```

Please, tell me any additional information I could provide to make this issue clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Option 1.)***

The documentation is assuming that you already have the image ic_menu in your resources folders (**app/App_Resources/Android/drawables-xxx** for Android and **app/App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets**). Example can be found [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/tree/master/app/App_Resources/Android/drawable-xhdpi)

If you do not have this image (scaled for the different devices) then you should provide it. The concept is pretty much the same as you would do for the AppIcons ([article here](https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/creating-launch-screens-ios#customizing-app-icons)). There are also tools for automatic generation of images with different scales - for example [this one here](http://nsimage.brosteins.com/).

***Option 2.)***

**Note**: this will work only with [the syntax for custom ActionItems](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#how-to-create-custom-title-view-instead-of-the-actionbar-title)

Another applicable option is to create your hamburger menu with [IconFonts](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/icon-fonts) instead of images (which will have to be resized precisely for the different resolutions)

Example:

1.) [Use this instead of image](http://fontawesome.io/icon/bars/)

2.) Import the icon font in folder fonts [example here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/tree/master/app/fonts)

3.) Create a CSS class

```
.font-awesome {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 14;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
```

4.) Apply the code for the glyph you want to use (in this case the hamburger menu)

```
<Button text="&#xf0c9;" class="font-awesome" tap="" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
But when I follow your example, I get a button with literally "&#xf0c9" instead of the unicode character of a hamburger menu =O

Comment: For android, the font-family property must be exactly the font file's name (without quote). For example, you have `app/fonts/fontawesome.tff`, then in CSS: `font-family: fontawesome;`

Comment: @DinhLe I did as you told: `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` is the file's name and the property in the css is `font-family: fontawesome-webfont` but it didn't worked =(

Comment: the name of the font in the CSS file should be FontAwesome exactly as shown in the example application - the name is repsected as the authors of the font has created it not by the name of the file

Comment: @NickIliev was right. I just forgot to add the ";" at the end of the value of text.
Thanks you both for your help! =D